# How to delete Excel data connection?

Tags: excel, powershell, connection

I found out that `$workbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete` in VBA deletes the data connection from an Excel sheet.

In PowerShell this is not working for me. `$workbook.Connections.Count()` works and returns a number of connections in PowerShell.

Any idea how I can delete these data connection with PowerShell?

Comment: $workbook.Connections[1].Delete() ?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I'd bet `$workbook.Connections | ForEach{$_.Delete()}` would probably do it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this $workbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete to this **$workbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete()**